# How to make my canvas animation to not loop

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

```
<script>      
function hum() {
    var width = 280,
        height = 210,
        frames = 3,

        currentFrame = 0,

        hump = document.getElementById("Canvas2").getContext('2d');
    humpImage = new Image()
    humpImage.src = 'images/hum.png';

    var draw = function () {
        hump.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        hump.drawImage(humpImage, 0, height * currentFrame, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

        if (currentFrame == frames) {
            currentFrame = 0;
        } else {
            currentFrame++;
        }
    }

    setInterval(draw, 150);

}
</script>
```

The above is a canvas animation javascript code . Here it loops automatically.. I want to make to cancel the loop and to play the canvas only on click how to do it.

Please spot light on this

Comment: Add an event handler for the click event. In that handler set a flag, 'clicked'. Now, change your above code - only call setInterval if this flag has not been set. You'll need to make the flag a global and initialize it to 0.

Comment: @enhzflep please explain briefly ,I can't understand your comment as I am a m new one for canvas animation.. please

Answer (score 0):

Saravan, theres a number of different ways you could go about this. Best practise, I believe is to use the RequestAnimationFrame function, though I don't seem to find any old source code here in which I've used it.

I notice in your code, each time around the draw-loop, you call setInterval. Unless I'm mistaken, the correct function to use there is actually `setTimeOut`. As you can see from my code, (and js help) the function setInterval only needs to be called once.

When you call it, it gives you a unique identifier which can be used later to remove the interval handler. That's the method I've used. When the button is clicked, the interval is set and it's handle saved. Then, when the canvas is clicked, I simply remove the interval handler.

It's late and I'm tired. This should give you plenty to go on.

**EDIT: new code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

var drawIntervalHandle;
var hump, humpImage, isRunning = false;
var width = 44,height = 128,frames = 3,currentFrame = 0;
var myImageSource = 'thermometer.png';

function mInit()
{
    byId('Canvas2').addEventListener('click', onCanvasClick, false);
    initAndStartAnim();
}

function onCanvasClick()
{
    if (isRunning)
    {
        clearInterval(drawIntervalHandle);
        isRunning = false;
        byId('status').innerHTML = "Stopped, frame: " + currentFrame;
    }
    else
    {
        drawIntervalHandle = setInterval(draw, 150);
        isRunning = true;
    }
}

function draw() 
{
    hump.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    hump.drawImage(humpImage, 0, height * currentFrame, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

    if (currentFrame == frames)
        currentFrame = 0;
    else 
        currentFrame++;
    byId('status').innerHTML = "Running, frame: " + currentFrame;
}

function initAndStartAnim() 
{
    var can = document.getElementById("Canvas2");
    can.width = width;
    can.height = height;
    hump = can.getContext('2d');
    humpImage = new Image()
    humpImage.src = myImageSource;

    drawIntervalHandle = setInterval(draw, 150);
    isRunning = true;
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='Canvas2'>Canvas not supported if you see this. :(</canvas>
<br>
<div id='status'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand your program .. but I cannot implement on mine.. So when you have time please edit my code and do thre helpful

Comment: @Saravaankumar - this is generally considered poor etiquete. You haven't even asked me to fix your code, you've actually told me to do it and tacked a 'please' on before the demand. I expect that this is something simply lost in the translation to english. I will edit my answer in a minute or two. You'll have to change (a) the image source and (b) the dimensions of the canvas. The animation is started on page load, you can stop/resume it by clicking on the canvas. I also added a status message, so you know the play state and the current frame. Hope its helpful.

Comment: Another help  I am developing a javascript application.. I am embedding a image in it

I want some animation like whenever I touch the image a sparkle of stars or particle should scatter for a moment.. Is anyone know how to do. If so I want to know how to do that please let me know about it. by giving me a code example this is for my start uo project so please help me